# Can you tell me how comparison works, type operator == (arguments)

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to compare two instances, how the skeleton of the method should be and how to recall it in the main.

in the file.h

`type operator==(const& className1, const& className2);` like that?

in the file.cpp

```
type operator==(const& className1, const& className2){

..................
}
```

like that?

How do I call this back in the main.cpp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

operator== is invoked automatically whenever the compiler encounters an expression a == b where a and b are not both primitive types. Also, the return type should generally be bool.

Answer (score 2):

`Type operator==(Type,Type)` is an example of Operator Overloading.  The goal of Operator Overloading is to make code simpler to read.  When you call the `==` operator in `main` on two arguments of type `Type` the compiler will use overload resolution to detect that it should use your operator.

```
Type operator==(Type,Type); // usually in .h file
int main(){
    Type a;
    Type b;
    cout << (a==b) << endl; // calls operator==(Type,Type)
}
```

Comment: in the file.h  bool operator==(const Vector<Data>& a) const;  while in the main.cpp  bool operator==(lasd::Vector<int>,lasd::Vector<int>);                                                
 int main(){

  lasd::Vector<int> v;
  lasd::Vector<int> c; cout << (v==c) << endl;